# Having a hard time "verb-ing" vs having a hard time to "verb"

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between:

> Having a hard time "verb-ing" *vs*
>   Having a hard time to "verb"

For example:

> I'm having a hard time **explaining** *vs*
>   I'm having a hard time **to explain**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that the first form is correct. There's no general rule, the required form depends on the context. For instance, these ARE correct:

*It was hard to explain*

*I found it hard to explain*

*I had difficulty explaining it*

*I did not know how to explain it*

*Explaining it was hard*

The form used doesn't depend on the verb itself, only on the context. For instance, it's also correct to say

*Describing it was hard.*

Comment: When I search on google ""I'm having a hard time to"", I find [3M of results](https://www.google.be/search?q=%22I%27m+having+a+hard+time+to%22&oq=%22&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j69i57j69i59l2.1013j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) with the second form I said, so I don't understand when it is correct to use that?

Comment: @Jirei: If you want to go by the numbers, "I am having a hard time to explain" has 8 hits including this question. "I am having a hard time explaining" has 12000 hits.

Comment: @Jirei - Next time you've done some research like that, you should include that in your original question. Folks here appreciate that kind of research is done ahead of time, and you're more likely to get more upvotes.

Comment: non-native speakers do write things on the internet