# Further question about the difference between "having a hard time Verb+ing" and "having a hard time to Verb"

Tags: sentence-construction, difference, expressions, grammaticality-in-context

This question was once raised by Jirei and answered by MSalters already at the link below.

[Having a hard time "verb-ing" vs having a hard time to "verb"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170418/having-a-hard-time-verb-ing-vs-having-a-hard-time-to-verb)

I, however,  would like to raise the same question once again because the ***"having a hard(or difficult/tough/good/bad etc.) time to Verb"*** structure can also be seen even in some of well-known prestigious media although not very often, and the answer given in the post at the above link does not clarify that point.

Please refer to the below links for some examples.

TIME Magazine

> "North Korea will ***have a difficult time to make*** this power
> transition."
> https://world.time.com/2012/02/16/kim-jong-un-gets-thumbs-up-from-north-koreans-in-japan/

Newsweek

> If you are ***having a difficult time to save*** despite budgeting,
> here's what we recommend:
> https://www.newsweek.com/amplify/5-realistic-money-managing-strategies-financially-free-investing-tools

The New York Times

> "The Greeks certainly will ***have a difficult time to explain*** the
> deal to their voters," Mr. Schäuble said.
> https://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/21/business/international/greece-debt-eurozone-finance-ministers.html

BBC

> The 23-year-old from County Down is passionate about encouraging
> others who are ***having a difficult time to speak out*** and get the
> help they need.
> https://www.bbc.com/news/av/uk-northern-ireland-49994093/student-mental-health-you-d-seek-help-for-a-broken-leg

I now understand that ***"having a hard time Verb+ing"*** structure is a lot more common than ***"having a hard time to Verb"*** format, but as you can see above, the latter sentence construction is also quoted in some well-known news media, so I just wonder if it is not a matter of right or wrong, but just a matter of naturalness or awkwardness depending on where you are from or what industry you are in?

Comment: Finding something in a Google search doesn't means that it's grammatical. Google's database is also full of people who've made errors in one way or another. None of the examples in the question are idiomatic or grammatical. This question remains a duplicate of the other, despite these examples.

Comment: This is still a duplicate of [Having a hard time "verb-ing" vs having a hard time to "verb"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170418/having-a-hard-time-verb-ing-vs-having-a-hard-time-to-verb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Ngram Viewer [shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20hard%20time%20getting%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20get%2Ca%20hard%20time%20keeping%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20keep%2Ca%20hard%20time%20finding%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20find%2Ca%20hard%20time%20making%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20make%2Ca%20hard%20time%20holding%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20hold%2Ca%20hard%20time%20being%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20be&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20getting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20get%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20keeping%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20keep%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20finding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20find%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20making%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20make%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20holding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20hold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20being%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20getting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20get%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20keeping%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20keep%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20finding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20find%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20making%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20make%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20holding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20hold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20being%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hard%20time%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0) that 'a hard time to V' is used very rarely compared with 'a hard time V-ing'. I haven't fully checked the other words you list, but I suspect the same applies. If a student asked me this in class, I would immediately say 'a hard time V-ing'. 'a hard time to V' sounds awkward to me, and reading it in the major sources you have linked doesn't convince me otherwise.

'[be] a difficult time to V' sounds better than '[have] a difficult to V'. I could more easily say 'It's a difficult time to stay fit' than 'I'm having a difficult time staying fit' (compare 'I'm having a difficult time staying fit').

Comment: Thanks, Sydney. I tend to dig into details about why A is not acceptable while B is okay, and often asks native speakers for the reason from grammatical point of view. I should simply take it that that's the way native speakers speak, but when  finding those uncommon (or less common) expressions in major sources, I again start to feel like "why"?